# insert rows with a loop in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, sql-insert

I have to insert some rows for each product with a loop but i receive a syntax error. i dont know why.

This is my query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertURL()
BEGIN

    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    WHILE (i <= 120) DO
        INSERT INTO product_images (alt, url, `index`, product_id) 
                VALUES ('productImage', 'image/products/producte.png', 1, i);
                VALUES ('productImage', 'image/products/producte.png', 0, i);
                VALUES ('productImage', 'image/products/producte.png', 0, i);                               
                VALUES ('productImage', 'image/products/producte.png', 0, i);               
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

And i receive this error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 4

Comment: Procedure looks fine but you don't appear to be setting delimiters,

Comment: is there any solution?? @P.Salmon

Comment: Set delimiters..?

Comment: Multi-row `INSERT` syntax:  `INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (1,2,3),(11,22,33), ... ,(66,55,44);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0 (or MariaDB 10.2 or higher), you can use a recursive query for this. This should be much more efficient that using a loop.

```
insert into product_images (alt, url, `index`, product_id) 
with recursive cte as (
    select 0 i
    union all select i + 1 from cte where i < 120
)
select 
    'productImage',
    'image/products/producte.png', 
    x.n, 
    c.i
from cte c
cross join (select 1 n union all select 0 union all select 0 union all select 0) x
```

The recursive common table expression generates numbers from `0` to `120`. We can then `cross join` it with a fixed list of values `(1, 0, 0, 0)` to generate the rows for `insert`.

You can easily turn this to a procedure:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure inserturl()
begin
    insert into product_images (alt, url, `index`, product_id) 
    with recursive cte (
        select 0 i
        union all select i + 1 from cte where i < 120
    )
    select 
        'productImage',
        'image/products/producte.png', 
        x.n, 
        c.i
    from cte c
    cross join (select 1 n union all select 0 union all select 0 union all select 0) x;
end
$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: how can i know i use which version?? i got an error again @GMB

Comment: @ali: `select version()`

Comment: i use 10.4.6-MariaDB version but i got a new error like mine. syntax error at line 5 @GMB

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near  'select 0 i union all select i + 1 from cte where i < 120 ) se' at line 5 @GMB

Comment: I am unsure how you are running the query exactly. This works fine for me in Maria DB 10.3 and 10.4 in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f6f68c934c971f52fdd25731b36db014)

Comment: copy and past and f9 :) @GMB

Comment: @ali: If I can't reproduce your issue I can't fix it... Please check my the db fiddle I linked in the previous comment, and use the very same query. Or else, try to reproduce the issue that you are getting in the fiddle.

Comment: thanks for you'r help but i fixed my problem with another solution. but i have to say when i restart heidiSQl you'r query and mine worked as well without any error. but i used eloquent ORM to fix my problem. thank you :) @GMB